# Copy one test set and paste into different folder using OTA

Tags: qtp, ota

I would like to copy one test from one folder to another folder in Quality center using OTA/Vbscript. Any help on this much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you just using QC or do you use QTP as well? If you use QTP and need to move tests from one folder to another then the easiest way is to probably just write the VBscript to achieve this.

```
dim sourceFolder
set sourceFolder=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If sourceFolder.FileExists([path to your file(s)]) Then
sourceFolder.MoveFile "[file]", "[destination]"
End If
```